# Grails how to allow orphan of many to one

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Can grails allow a many relationship to be orphaned with domain class instructions?
i.e. When I delete a related one relationship the corresponding column on the many is set to NULL.

the one

```
 class TrackingNumber{
       static hasMany=[records:AttendanceRecords]

}
```

the many

```
class AttendanceRecord{
     static belongsTo=[site:Site, number:TrackingNumber]

     static constraints={
           number(nullable:true)
     }
}
```

It seems deleting TrackingNumber instance tries to delete all of the Attendance records as well, which is undesired. I'd rather not have to removeFrom() each association in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems deleting TrackingNumber instance tries to delete all of the
>   Attendance records as well, which is undesired.

The `belongsTo` is causing the deletes to cascade.

Instead of this...

```
class AttendanceRecord{
    static belongsTo=[site:Site, number:TrackingNumber]

    static constraints={
        number(nullable:true)
    }
}
```

You can do this...

```
class AttendanceRecord{
    static belongsTo=[site:Site]
}
```

Comment: More info on cascades may be found at http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.9/guide/GORM.html#cascades

Comment: So am I interpreting the docs correctly as answering the question "no"? Seems you can specify cascading an entire delte or ignoring the relationship altogether, but I don't see clear documentation about setting relationship to null.

Comment: Made the changes you suggested. That was the ticket once I found some lingering MYSQL foreign key constraint...